# Phonegap Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu

Seems that I can't get it right, or I'm doing it wrong

I'm using ubuntu/elementary OS

I added the paths to

`tail ~/.bashrc`

Gives me this

```
export HOME="/home/jsantana"
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Downloads/android-studio/sdk"
export PATH="$PATH:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
```

`echo $PATH`

returns this

```
//home/jsantana/Downloads/android-studio/sdk/tools://home/jsantana/Downloads/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools
```

BUT when I run `sudo phonegap run android` on my testapp it returns this error

```
$ sudo phonegap run android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run android'...
cp: no such file or directory: /home/jsantana/phonegap/testapp/icon.png


Running command: /home/jsantana/phonegap/testapp/platforms/android/cordova/run 

ERROR: Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.

Error: /home/jsantana/phonegap/testapp/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Really not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

The paths are correct but still says they are incorrect

EDIT:

so I changed a bit but still get the same error:

```
export HOME="/home/jsantana"
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Downloads/android-studio/sdk"
export PATH="${PATH}:/home/jsantana/Downloads/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools"
export PATH="${PATH}:/home/jsantana/Downloads/android-studio/sdk/tools"
```

when I `$ echo $PATH`

```
/home/jsantana/Downloads/android-studio/sdk/tools:/home/jsantana/Downloads/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools
```

getting same error

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run android'...
cp: no such file or directory: /home/jsantana/phonegap/testapp/icon.png


Running command: /home/jsantana/phonegap/testapp/platforms/android/cordova/run 

ERROR: Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.

Error: /home/jsantana/phonegap/testapp/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Comment: shouln't "//home/" be "/home/"?

Comment: Try changing `export PATH="$PATH:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"` to `export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"`

Comment: I did that and still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

try like this one

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/jsantana/Downloads/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/jsantana/Downloads/android-studio/sdk/tools
```

Comment: I added a few more stuff in the question after doing your changes I still get the error :(